# Is it possible to set inputView/ inputAccessoryView for textfields in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, inputview, inputaccessoryview

I have picker and toolbar for textfields.

```
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!

    @IBOutlet weak var toTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fromTF: UITextField!
```

and then in viewDidLoad

```
fromTF.inputView = picker
toTF.inputView   = picker
fromTF.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
toTF.inputAccessoryView   = toolbar
```

Is it possible to avoid this code and set them in `storyboard`? (Like you do that for delegates, etc.) I can't find any possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible. You can set the views up in your Storyboard/Xib as yo have done, but it looks like the actual connection logic needs to take place in code.

Comment: Seems for me, it impossible too :(